# Can someone explain how this is possible: <parentmodule>.<submodule1> and <parentmodule>.<submodule2> have two different parent locations?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import openai_ros.msg
>>> import openai_ros.task_envs
>>> print openai_ros.msg.__file__
/home/simulations/public_sim_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openai_ros/msg/__init__.py
>>> print openai_ros.task_envs.__file__
/home/simulations/public_sim_ws/src/all/openai_ros/openai_ros/src/openai_ros/task_envs/__init__.py
```

1. How is it possible that two submodules have different parent paths?
2. Given I have access to these files and directories, is there a way to manually reinstall the modules so that they would work on a new, clean python 2.7 install?

Comment: See https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages